# Can't unlock LG Optimus P500

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out

I have an LG Optimus P500 phone with Gingerbread.

Suddenly I am not able to unlock it by drawing the pattern. I remember the exact pattern, but its not showing what I draw there. It's not even turning its light on when I draw it.

Removed battery, re-inserted, and done every primary thing.

Strangely I can receive phone call by swiping to answer.

Tried turning it on by pressing power button + home button, but it went to some fast reboot mode and nothing happened.

Can anybody help me in repairing my phone?

Comment: What options do you have under the pattern dots? Is there any option to unlock it using your gmail username and password?

Comment: See: [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is HARD RESET Your Device.

Before it,try wrong  pattern continuously for 10-15 times .It will show some option where u can unlock your screen with your Google play account.

If it doesn't work try hard reset.

For hard reset

1. Switch off your phone.
2. press power button+volume up/down(try both separately) for 10-12 seconds.
3. It will show several option .
4. choose the appropriate one (don't choose options which you don't understand)

for selecting the menu press 'menu' button or try some other buttons if it doesn't work.
the menu choice depends on the different versions of Android phone.

Comment: Bad advice to just factory-reset and lose all data ;) Luckily you gave at least one alternative first. More alternatives can be found here: [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)