# Simulate Touchscreen Input On Android?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens, touchscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/cannot-unlock-tablet-as-have-no-internet-connection)

I have had a very unfortunate accident with my Samsung Galaxy S2 and the screen has suffered a complete shatter (top to bottom! - was closed in a car door)

I have downloaded and am running Droid@Screen to make sure the phone itself isn't damaged and can see that the screen is sat on the pattern lock screen. Is there a way I can simulate a touchscreen input from the PC?

I just need to unlock the screen then can use Kies Air to remove all of my pics and videos and important files.

Any help would be appreciated, I really need to get these files off :(

Comment: See this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/cannot-unlock-tablet-as-have-no-internet-connection) for more details.

Comment: @t0mm13b How is that question related?

Comment: @LiamW how to bypass lock screen and get at the data  due to broken screen.. :)

Comment: That question has nothing to do with a broken screen...

Comment: @LiamW Doesn't matter for what reason he needs to bypass the pattern lock, does it? He needs to bypass it (quote: *I just need to unlock the screen*), and the linked Q gives a lot of examples on how to achieve that. Hence +1 from me to t0mm13b ;)

Comment: @t0mm13b - Thanks for the info, unfortunately my Wifi is turned off and so is my USB debugging... I have literally left no options to help myself. I've locked myself out of my phone unless I can get my touchscreen to respond somehow :(

Comment: Hmmm.... @Izzy, is it possible to inject via `sendevent`, oh wait... the OP's usb debugging is switched off... :( was thinking along the lines of the android testing tool called `monkey`... :\

Comment: @T0mm13b I thought I could try the SDK tools too but they all require debugging switched on... I think I just have to accept that I can't get my data back. The only thing I can think off is possible lashing up a mouse to my phone through the USB port and somehow trying to draw the lockscreen blind lol...

Comment: hummm... as matter of interest, do you have ClockworkMod recovery installed? If you have, you could try resetting the phone by pulling the battery for a few seconds, then put back in battery, press power and hold down volume down key to get into recovery, then you'd be in a rooted environment which you could mount the partition and get at the data?!

Comment: @LiamBee if your device is rooted, you can get ADB access in recovery mode. Just follow the link t0mm13b posted -- my answer there has a bunch of possibilities. Though without a working screen, the set is markably reduced...

Comment: No im not rooted either, I used to be but planned on returning the phone for an upgrade in the new year (not sure where you guys are, but I cant return if rooted in the UK)... Another avenue blocked off by me lol