# Performing a Factory Reset a woo tablet

Tags: tablet, factory-reset

I'm trying to perform a factory reset on a locked tablet, because of too many incorrect password attempts.

I found [these](http://support.google.com/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2668187) instructions. But now all I see is a droid lying down with a red warning sign on its stomach. When I press the volume down, nothing happens. There is no menu either.

Comment: That is for a Nexus 7 tablet. Is there a model number for your tablet? I can't find anything for a "Woo Tablet"

Comment: Apparently if I press only volume down and power I reach a menu. The problem is it is all in Chinese. If I press around it appears to be a testing interface of sorts. Emitting sounds and turning of the camera

Comment: Usually holding VolDown + Power is for the recovery menu (Where you can do a reset), but without knowing exactly what tablet you have I am afraid I don't have any real information for you, and I doubt anyone else will either.

Comment: **You don't need to wipe all your data with a factory reset to get back into your phone due to too many incorrect attempts.** See here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847