# I can't use my Google Account password to bypass the lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, google-account, password, locked-out

On my CM9 / ICS 4.0 phone, if I incorrectly enter the drawn pattern five times in a row, it locks itself for 30 seconds. I can't enter any more passwords, but I can click a "forgot my password" button and enter my Google Account password.

On my rooted 4.0.3 tablet running a custom ROM, my lock screen is set with a numeric PIN. If I input it incorrectly five times or more, it locks itself and I can't enter any more passwords.

I'm not offered the option to enter my google account password to bypass this, although I have configured a Google account on the device.

I want to activate the "I forgot" button in order to enter my Google Account credentials. Is it possible?

Comment: You might also want to check [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/16575) for alternatives.

Comment: Favorited, but does not apply to my case: it does not ask me for credentials, and there is no "I forgot" button.

Comment: Understood. I just thought in case that would lock you out, it would be nice to have some solutions at hand.

Comment: Sorry @Izzy, I truly appreciate the effor of a great and active member! I had even upvoted your linked answer. Sorry if I sounded rude... =/

Comment: Unfortunately, for my case, apparently there's only the ADB option. I better NEVER forget my password, then. :(

Comment: You didn't sound rude, don't bother. I just wanted to state that I cought the mentioned fact, and my link was meant as a fallback -- exactly as you seems to have needed. Sorry to read that the ADB option is the only one left. In that case, take care that your brother-in-laws best friends little son/daughter does not tamper with it, using up all your "free tries" ;)

Answer (score 1):

It will not show if gapps aren't installed on the tablet (some more obscure brands don't come with gapps).

If gapps are installed, then try and enter it incorrectly 20+ times. This will lock you out. You will only see the enter google details screen if the device has gapps (Google Play, Gmail etc).

Comment: 20 times? Why is it 5 on my phone?

Comment: @ruda.almeida It's the different UI's. TabletUI must have changed to remove the reset password button.

Comment: 1. What is "TabletUI"? Never heard of it.

Comment: 2. I Have typed the incorrect code 20 times. It says "you have typed your PIN incorrectly NNN times, and every 5 times it locks itself for 30 seconds and tell me to wait. Nothing different happened on the 20th time.

Comment: @ruda.almeida Do you have gapps on the tablet?

Comment: I don't know what gapps are.