# Does Google know my screen lock PIN/password?

Tags: lock-screens, google-account, google

1. Where does Google save my screen lock password as it asks me to verify my Google account by entering it?
2. That means Google knows my screen lock password.
3. Where can I find that password in my Google account or from Google?

Comment: Your password doesn't leave your device and therefore Google **doesn't** know that//Android has a [key store mechanism](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) to make it impossible for anyone to access it

Comment: When does it ask to verify your Google account? Is it on ["forgot my password"](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/38555/44325)?

Comment: That could be the Google Factory Reset protection. Have you performed a factory reset using recovery menu? Android saves a hashed version of the Google account password to ensure you are the owner of the phone.

Comment: @AndrewT. when i try to login to my google/gmail account and i have activated two factor authentication i guess , so in many option "try another way" like it is asking me to verify that's it's my account by otp, or by screen lock password

Comment: @beeshyams   how to find that, help me i forgot my screen lock password , and also usb debugging is not enabled on my phone,i want to save my data because it is showing that service center guy will restore it to factory settings and i will loose all my data, and some guys are suggesting like by doing some trick like scratching in some part of motherboard can unlock , help me out is there any way to save my data

Comment: @Jimmi I am really sorry but can't think of a way

Comment: @AndrewT. how to find that, help me i forgot my screen lock password , and also usb debugging is not enabled on my phone,i want to save my data because it is showing that service center guy will restore it to factory settings and i will loose all my data, and some guys are suggesting like by doing some trick like scratching in some part of motherboard can unlock , help me out is there any way to UNLOCK MY SCREEN and save my data.

Comment: no pin, no data recovery, sorry. that is called 'security'

Comment: @alecxs  is there no way like ,by using adb command like deleting gesture.key or any other way , some guy told me they can unlock by scratching in some part of motherboard, is that possible, it's like ip or ic scractching

Comment: @alecxs   Device - oppo reno 2f.   android version- 9 or 11.  it's an screen lock 6 digit pin

Answer (score 1):

While every app is different, and there is no general way to know for certain what data is being collected/transferred, a common practice is to use a hashed/seeded string of a password (instead of the password itself).

In this way, the password can be entered on your device, password is hashed/seeded, and only the hash is sent to a central server for comparison (the server also should only have the hashed/seeded string stored, and not the actual password).

When the hashed/seeded strings match, access is granted, as this indicates the original password was entered correctly.

This is not without its problems, but they are seldom realized in actuality.

---

For more information:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right