# How to unlock android phone which is locked by entering wrong pin

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens

I have a Pantech Burst Android phone runs on ICS 4.0.4. Which got locked by entering wrong pin several times. Now it is asking to login to Gmail to unlock the phone but neither phone data nor wifi is enabled.
How to unlock it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Weird case, it should give you an option to connect to a wifi hotspot when its locked and needs a connection. Try waiting for an hour, if I remember there is a 30min cooldown if too many attempts failed.

Comment: All methods known to me are presented in an answer to [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575). The topic sounds like an exact match to yours, by the way :) Good luck!