# Security lock pattern

Tags: locked-out, pattern-lock

My son playing with my phone used up the number of times the lock pattern allows. Now my phone is locked. I use a Gionee Dual sim phone with 4.1 Jelly Bean. Any suggestion???

Comment: Yupp: See the [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for first aid -- or directly jump to [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575). (hint: hovering your mouse over tags reveals useful hints, and behind the 'info' tag there, you often find first-aid)

Answer (score 0):

if you have USB debugging enabled already you could disable the lockscreen with:

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases
sqlite3 settings.db
update system set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock';
update system set value=0 where name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently';
.quit
```

Reboot, and then:

```
adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key
```

Reboot one more time.

**If you don't have USB debugging already enabled there is no way to use this.**

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1800799)