# Factory reset without accessing phone settings

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, factory-reset, locked-out, pattern-lock, micromax-a35

I have a **Micromax A35 Android(2.3.5)** phone which has been locked by repeated wrong attempts of the pattern lock.

Now the display screen asks me to enter my Google account username and password, but the WiFi and the mobile networks are disabled.

Is there a way to factory reset the phone without having access to the settings?

Answer (score 1):

First, even without having a network connection, you can try to unlock it with your Google account data. Usually the device stores a "token", so you might be able to log in.

Second, if that does not help, you might want to take a look at the [locked-out](/questions/tagged/locked-out) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), and at [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575). There might still be a chance to unlock your device.

If nothing else helps, a factory-reset can also be done from the [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode):

- Shut down your device
- hold the <kbd>Vol +</kbd> button and keep it pressed while additionally press the <kbd>Power</kbd> button. Keep both pressed until a text-menu appears
  (if that doesn't work, try again while substituting <kbd>Vol +</kbd> with <kbd>Vol -</kbd>)
- use the volume buttons to select "Factory Reset"
- execute the item (usually done by short-pressing the <kbd>Power</kbd> button or by pressing the 'show more' button at the bottom-left of your phone)

Comment: I tried the key combos: But I get the a screen with various TEST options with `Vol+`...and a fast boot with `Vol-`....All three together also didn't work....
but no option to reset the phone...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the device -- so the above was rather the "general way" as it works on most devices. But when you can enter fastboot mode, and have the fastboot tools on your laptop/PC, you might be able to do a `fastboot -w` (see [CyanogenMod Wiki: Fastboot](http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Fastboot)). See also [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) if you don't want to install the entire Android SDK for that.

Comment: thanks I tried that but, I keep getting error: device not found...

Comment: Which OS (Windows/Mac/Linux)? On Windows, you might need to install the device drivers first. On Linux (and most likely Mac, too) run `fastboot` as root.

Comment: @Izzy if someone steals a phone, they can reset it from fast boot and use it? Isn't this a security vulnerability?

Comment: @Rahul2001 where did I write that? Apart from which: This answer and all its comments are dated 2013. There was no FRP (factory-reset protection) introduced then. And btw: It would be a "security vulnerability" if they could use it *without a reset* (as that would give access to all data – while a factory-reset would make sure to *not* get to them easily).

Comment: @Izzy fair enough, it's just that a friend of mine claimed that he could use my phone of he got hold of it, and showed me the option in my fast boot menu. Wouldn't he be able to access all data on the SD card?

Comment: Not via fastboot. Don't get confused by that name, it doesn't even boot into Android. It's a mode where you can *write to the device* (intended to change partitioning and flash images), but cannot read from it.