# How to factory reset Micromax A35 H/W ver v2.0 S/W v8_0_9

Tags: factory-reset, micromax-a35

I tried all of above ideas but there is no display. Factory reset + and power button hold is shows various type of test about phone and i also tried fast mode solution device not detected with computer tell me what i will do for it i am tired.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, bishnu! Would you please [edit] your question and let us know what "above ideas" you are referring to? At least on my monitor, "above" it I only see the walls of my room. You might also want to check with our [factory-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info), which a.o. links to similar questions which already have answers. After that, please [edit] your question and let us know what you tried. If you succeeded, it's also a good idea to answer your own question yourself.

Comment: Oh, besides: I've just checked [questions tagged factory-reset containing micromax a35](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=micromax+a35+[factory-reset]), and found a very similar question: [Factory reset without accessing phone settings](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43696/16575). Guess what: it's about factory-resetting a Micromax A35, and has 4 answers. Maybe one of them can solve your "above" issue?