# How can I unlock a pattern lock if my screen is defunct?

Tags: lock-screens, broken-screen, pattern-lock

I have damaged the screen on my phone, so much so, it will not allow me to get the data to transfer onto my laptop. On opening Samsung Kies, it is saying that the connected device is locked. Please enter password on the connected device. I can only assume its the pattern lock they are referring to as I have managed to unlock the sim.

As I am unable to do this due to the screen being cracked, I wondered whether there is any other way of doing this, before sending the same onto my insurance company, as they are saying that I will lose all the data! Cant see why seeing as its just the hardware that is damaged and not the software.

Comment: Does the screen display anything at all?

Comment: No nothing whatsoever apart from the bottom part lighting up where the middle button is

Comment: Are you able to try to do your lock pattern on the screen without seeing exactly where it is?

Comment: So the objective is to get the data off the device? Have a look [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/cannot-unlock-tablet-as-have-no-internet-connection)

Answer (score 3):

YES That worked for me!!!

I've broken my screen, and after removing the SIM to another phone, the avast alarm starts louder every time I turn on.

1. Connect USB
2. Open KIES
3. Let the KIES waiting the screen unlock
4. Log in @ http://findmymobile.samsung.com/
5. Ensure choose the correct device, unlock the screen.
6. Done!!!!!

I did without the SIM card

Comment: What if the device isn't by Samsung?

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem on my tablet, and was able to solve it by attaching an USB mouse to unlock.

Please try if your device support USB mouse.

Answer (score 1):

If you can remember your Samsung account details, you can unlock the phone remotely using the [Samsung Find My Mobile site](http://findmymobile.samsung.com/login.do). The phone has to be on and connected to the internet.

Comment: Thanks, it works and save me... I cannot connect with Kies now

Comment: what if the phone isn't by Samsung?

Answer (score 0):

You can try take off the sim card, and try connect the phone in kies without sim card in phone, if this doesnot help you, look moborobo software. You can use a stream video function to see your phone screen on PC.
http://www.moborobo.com/download/moborobo_details.html

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I tried using moborobo and although it has detected my smartphone, it is saying that I meed to enable USB Debugging. This I cannot do due to not seeing anything on the screen. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: ZnewmaN, I tried doing my lock pattern on the screen without seeing exactly where it is, but nothing :-(

Comment: My father passed away in January and I have photos which are of sentimental value to me, hence why I am trying desperately to recover the photos that I have of him. If anything can be done before my phone goes back to the insurance company it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the password and you have Drop Box installed, you can use the Screen Capture Function if you have it. Even though I could not see the screen the screen capture would capture the screen. Plug in device, open Drop Box from the computer you are plugged into. When you capture the screen (Home Button and Power button at same time) it will upload the picture to Drop Box. Have Drop Box window open and refresh if needed. By doing this I was able to see the main screen and was able to best guess the fingering for the code. If you do it right you will verify it is unlocked with another screen capture. After unlocked you can use Kies to transfer data. Very time consuming, but worked for me. Hope this helps someone, it was a life saver for me.

Answer (score 0):

**TO HELP PEOPLE WITH THE PROBLEM IN THE FUTURE**

First, turn on Kies.

Then, connect your phone to the computer via usb.

Then, make sure you have the screen on.

after that, have someone call your phone.

it will bypass the lock screen and connect to kies.

Comment: This seemed too good to be true. Alas, I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked with me was, first Run Kies then connect the USB (you will get locked device screen in the Kies) then got to the internet and load the page findmymobile.samsung.com and log to your Samsung Account (SIM CARD MUST BE IN), in the Remote Control menu, choose Unlock my screen and then in the window by the side click Unlock, the program will then contact your phone and soon after you will get the message > Screen Unlocked.

Go to Kies and every thing will be there for you..... Good Luck.