# Back up files on a pattern locked phone

Tags: keyboard, backup, locked-out, google-account

A friend of mine tried to guess my pattern so my phone got locked, asking for gmail account and password. The thing is that i used to use a program for keyboard symbols cause one of the symbols there is $. However the phone is locked so i cannot use this program. I cannot write my password down. Am i doomed to factory reset? i can't remember if i have usb debugging enabled and my GT-B5512 is not rooted. I have literally searched everywhere for $ but i can't find it!!! Is there a way to connect my phone to pc in order to use its keyboard? Or another way to solve this?

Comment: Every standard keyboard on Android should be able to produce a `$`-sign. Are you able to switch the keyboard plane?

Comment: no i am not able to to switch the keyboard plane. I am from Europe so my phone is able to produce €, english pound and every other weird currency sign except the dollar sign :/

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [locked-out tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for some first aid, and then especially at [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575).

Comment: What if you hold down the pound key or another character?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.phonegg.com/Samsung/Galaxy-Y-Pro-Duos-B5512/Samsung-Galaxy-Y-Pro-Duos-B5512-1.jpg) what your phone looks like?

Comment: @ZnewmaN Yes but in place of $ in "Y" there is €

Answer (score 3):

Hook up an external keyboard with a Micro USB OTG adapter.

Monoprice has one here http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=108&cp_id=10833&cs_id=1083314&p_id=9724&seq=1&format=2

Answer (score 0):

The following performs a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset):

1. power off your android phone/tablet
2. press and hold <kbd>volume up</kbd> or <kbd>volume down</kbd> button
3. press <kbd>power</kbd> button along with holding <kbd>volume</kbd> button, press and hold it for 5 seconds, after 5 second release <kbd>power</kbd> button (but not volume button). After few you will see the root menu, now release the <kbd>volume</kbd> button also
4. move the cursor down to "wipe data " using the <kbd>volume down</kbd> button, to select it use the <kbd>power</kbd> button

Now your android phone/tablet will restart in 3 seconds; after the restart you will be able to use it again.

Comment: Well, the question is asking to "Back up files" in its title. From its text one can assume OP knows how to factory-reset ("wipe data"). And wiping data does not backup anything, on the contrary...