# How to unlock pattern on Nexus 4 [Developer Option: ON]

Tags: lock-screens, nexus-4

Even I have seen duplicated thread as in: [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/cannot-unlock-tablet-as-have-no-internet-connection)

But Here's my situation:

1. I have wifi/data turned off.
2. I have the developer option turned on and my laptop does recognized the device with usb plugged in. (As I'm android developer)
3. I'm using unrooted Nexus 4 .

---

Is there any way of unlock the screen using adb way, i.e: turn on the wifi? If no luck I would probably go with hard reset.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally got it solved using a developer way. :)

Here's my reference for my solution: [Turn on wifi via self-made android applicaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033757/turn-off-wifi-via-adb/12420590#12420590)

Got the wifi the moment I compiled into my Nexus phone, and volla! It works and I got my phone back after login through Google account!

I hoped this thread might helped people who came across this problem as a developer.