# How to reset android phone which is locked and debugging mode is disabled, plus no recovery?

Tags: locked-out, micromax-a57

Anyone know how to reset an android phone which is locked and asking for gmail id/pass and can't boot into recovery mode, plus debugging mode is disabled?

Comment: Have you checked the answers of [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575), as I hinted to in chat? Plenty of solutions on how to overcome the pattern lock (you wrote in chat that you're stuck with that).

Comment: Which model do you own? There are different ways to do it across manufacturer and even make.

Answer (score 0):

It can be booted in safe mode. Just you have to do is switch off the phone and switch it on while pressing power key + volume down key simultaneously ( checked in micromax a116 ). If you are not able to switch it off, just remove the battery directly.;p
Note : The key combination may vary depends on the mobile brands.

Comment: Does booting into safe mode circumvent the lock screen? That would be bad news, security-wise. Also, all descriptions about safe mode state something like "[...] and keep holding the Menu key until you see the lock screen" -- so there you are.

Comment: @Izzy - It has no physical button other than the volume keys and power button, so that isn't working. And thanks a lot Izzy, for going out of your way to help me. :) Also thanks to Abhishek, I'm sure I'll get somewhere with this, sooner or later.

I've tried booting into recovery mode(safe mode?), and it isn't working.

Comment: @alvasrawuther I was not focussing on the menu button. I was rather pointing out that booting into safe-mode won't help you at all: note the *until you **see the lock screen*** -- which means, even when booting into safe-mode, you'll end up at the very same lock screen.

Comment: @Izzy - Oh, missed that then. :)

Answer (score -1):

On your WiFi connectivity or data connectivity just call the locked mobile number with another number and as you get the bell ringing you get some access for calling options just drag down the drop down list and on your WiFi. It's done now get an open source WiFi connectivity and now your mobile can be unlocked by entering your Gmail ID and password.