# forgot my google account password

Tags: security, lock-screens, pattern-lock

someone used my phone GT-S5300 and had wrongly tried the unlock pattern many times and now it is asking me for google account but i have forgotten my password. pliz suggest me how can i get my password back and unlock it.

Comment: Related: [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Answer (score 4):

The password recovery is the same as recovering your forgotten Google account password. On your computer, go to [Google Account Recovery](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery) and follow the instructions there. The process depends on many things, such as do you have 2-step verification installed, do you have backup codes or have you set up an alternate email.