# Password Recovery

Tags: google-account

Hoping you can help me fix my problem. I reset my phone (Acer z150) , all data erased. This is my problem how can I sign in in Clash of Clans without my google password. All I know is my Google email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either follow the instructions in [forgot my google account password](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45054/forgot-my-google-account-password) to reset your Google account's password, or follow [Supercell's instructions](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?s=how-to-contact-us&f=how-to-contact-us&p=web) (quoted below) about recovering your lost account.

> If your account was at any point linked to Game Center or Google Play, logging into the respective account and opening the game should retrieve it.
>
> If that does not work, please start a new game, and message us directly from within that new game.

Comment: okay .. but is it possible to retrieve my coc account even without the password only the email.? what is the fastiest way to retreive it ? can you help me? I will give you my email. or village name of my coc .

Comment: I'm not Supercell, so giving me your email or village name won't achieve anything. You need to contact them following the instructions I linked.