# Forgot login pattern on my tablet

Tags: locked-out

I have forgotten the Patten to get in my tablet. It is an Android system. The brand is IMPRESSION, model no.: i10-LE.

Comment: Sorry, but this site does not work like that (sending you emails in a specified format). We are a Q **& A** site, that means we hold both parts together. Besides, your question has already been answered multiple times here, see e.g. [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. I have never used a site like this before.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. Though I recommend at least having a look at the [FAQ] of our site(s). Might save you some headache :) And won't take that much time, as we tried keeping it short to not scare people away #D

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your tablet is in WiFi or in airplane mode? And you can't unlock it without? There's a [way](http://chethaka.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/unlock-an-android-device/) to solve this:

- Windows PC
- Install android SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- Connect the device with USB cable
- Install USB drivers

Open CMD:

Change directory to the android SDK platform tools (for example C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools)

Type following commands in CMD:

- adb devices (verify device is identified by pc. If not reconnect
  device and try again. it should display “device” with a serial no)
- adb shell
- cd /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases
- sqlite3 settings.db
- update system set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock';
- update secure set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock'; (for
  some devices update “system” is enough but I had to update “secure”
  too)
- update system set value=0 where
  name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently';
- update secure set value=0 where
  name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently';
- .quit
- exit
- adb reboot

Now your device should be unlocked. If not do this step too:

- adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key

Comment: For Readers: Root access is required to run some commands.