# How to change a pattern unlock from the phone settings without knowing the original

Tags: pattern-lock

I have two unlock security options set up on my phone (HTC One). Firstly there is the facial recognition (which works well and lets me in) but on the occasions when it is too dark / doesn't recognise my face then it falls back to pattern unlock.

However, I have no idea what this pattern is as I set it up ages ago and the facial recognition works quite well so I've not had to use it.

I can get into the phone fine with face unlock, and can get to the security settings, but I can't change anything without first having to enter my unlock pattern.

If I can't reset this pattern that means I can't ever shave or change my haircut for fear of not being recognised by the phone!

Can I disable / reset the pattern security from within the phone? I have also got AirDroid set up on my laptop so that might open another route if I can't do anything from the phone itself.

Comment: See [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575). My answer there includes an example to reset the pattern. As you still can access your device (face-unlocked), that one should be easy for you. Btw: If you never shave, the long beard might be problematic for face-unlock as well :)

Comment: @izzy thanks, but I was hoping there was an option from within the phone itself for me to do this, as I still have (mostly) full access to everything. Installed a paid app to get around it would be a last resort (only a few quid, but still!). I've updated the link in that answer too as it went to a dead page.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, Jon! Sorry to hear this app got converted into a paid one for a price like that; it was free before. Still, if one's really locked out it might be worth its price, as it might save a lot of headache...