# My screen lock problem

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, locked-out

Respected sir,
With due respect & humble submission I like to inform you that my Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos S6802 phone is lock due to many time drawing wrong screen pattern.

So, sir I request to you please solve my problem as early as possible

Comment: All available steps are described in the answers to [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575). You might also want to take a look at the [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 (if you have your Google Account)**

- Keep Drawing the pattern number of times
- Then at one time it will recognize that you forgot your pattern
- Then it will ask for your E Mail ID and password
- Type them then you can log in

**Solution 2 (If you forget your Google Account)**

- Power Off
- Press Volume Up + Home Key + Power Button
- It will start in recovery mode
- Select Factory Reset option using Power key.

Hope it works.