# Locked Nexus 7 - no forgotten password option

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out

My girlfriend forgot her password on her Nexus 7 and can't remember it. It's written everywhere on the web that you can use the gmail login after 5 wrong passwords but it doesn't seem to work anymore! It doesn't ask for the gmail account and never shows the forgotten password option.

I have tried to repeat the process on my Galaxy Nexus and there is no forgotten option either....

After 5 attempts it blocks for 30 seconds and I actually tried 30 times to see if after a while the gmail option appears but it's not the case...

How to use the gmail account to unlock the latest android devices (4.2.2)?

P.S. my phone isn't locked! I just try to redo her steps

Comment: Please check with [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) if one of the solutions works (all known methods are handled there). Then let us know if your issue solved.

Comment: My problem is that is not even asking for the Google account... And the WiFi is on.

Comment: Are you using a pattern lock, or a password? In the first case, the option to "disable pattern lock via ADB" does not mention any Google account related things, for one example. In the latter I must apologize, as the linked question refers to pattern lock =:-0

Comment: We are both using the password lock.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I just tried it on my own device (Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2) and indeed you are right: There is no restoring option when using a password or PIN. It only shows up for me when using a pattern.

There is still a method I just figured out.

1. Log in to your Google Account.
2. Go to https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager
3. Accept the device manager pop up and click on your device on "Lock".
4. Enter a new password.

I just tried it and it works very well here :)

Best regards!
visi0nary

*Edit: I just figured out that you need to have "Remote Wipe and Lock" enabled in Android Device Manager on your device. I hope your GF has enabled that option.*

*Edit: This only works for the original (admin) account on a Nexus 7. Device Manager is not available for other accounts.*

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be that the Android device in question has no Google account registered to it.  Can you install apps to it from the [Google Play web store](https://play.google.com)?

Comment: We both have a Google account linked on the device.