# Can the administrator on a Nexus 7 unlock a secondary user's password?

Tags: nexus-7, password

I've forgotten my password for the family's shared Nexus 7. We assumed that the primary user would be able to access my settings and reset the p/w for me, but it appears not.  I would prefer not to have to delete my account, and then recreate it, because I don't want to lose the various apps I've installed, and – frankly – I don't want the hassle! Can anyone help?
P.S. Note to self: next time, don't pick a password I am likely to forget.

Comment: Are you willing/able to run adb? See the following page: http://www.matthewhollander.com/locked-out-of-your-android-phone/ -- although in the end a factory reset and a reinstall of the apps might be the quickest solution.

Comment: Is it your lockscreen password, or the password on your Googel account that you've forgotten? If it's the lockscreen password have a look at this question (and the ones linked from it): [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/). If its your Google account that you don't know the password for then try going through the wizard at https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/