# Pin deleted but pin lock screen still comes up

Tags: lock-screens, samsung, vpn, locked-out

I was fooling around with VPN on my non-rooted Galaxy Note II and created a PIN as required. When I was done I disabled VPN and disabled the PIN by entering my PIN again. Later on my screen locked and it now requires a PIN to unlock. My old pin does not work and there is no new pin. I cannot get the prompt to unlock via my Gmail info after entering the wrong pin 50 times.

How can I get into my phone? I am hoping for an answer other than wiping my phone.

Comment: I've just added the appropriate tag (locked-out). Please see its favorite question: [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) It gives all variants of remedy currently known in its answers.

Answer (score 0):

There ONLY way to get into your phone is to wipe all downloaded applications but keep all data on your internal sd card. This can be done by switching off the phone. Then hold the volume up button and press the switch on button. Select to delete all user data. Do not worry as this will not delete data on your internal SD Card. Select reboot. The proccess of selecting is done by volume buttons. You confirm using the MENU button.  If backed your apps with ES File Explorer you can have them back without any internet connection. Select the back app file in MY FILES and install all your apps back again without any internet connection.