# Locked out of my phone. How can I backup my sms?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, locked-out, samsung-galaxy-y-duos

I am locked out of my Samsung Galaxy y Duos Lite and I have forgotten my password. USB debugging is not turned on. Is there any way to backup my sms onto my pc??

Comment: Your first read should be: [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Reset your google account password on a computer and login with the new password.