# No way to access recovery menu in android china tablet

Tags: recovery-mode

My Quest tablet is accidentally locked yesterday it asking for gmail and password but i forgot the gmail id and password.So after a long search i found lots of things such as unlocking tablet pattern lock,gmail lock,pin lock etc.These topics only be successfull only when the tablet is in recovery mode.So i tried to put my tablet into recovery mode by pressing vol + and power button.But there appears a android bot lying with red traiangle exlamation.So i simply tried to access recovery menu by pressing power and the vol + .But nothing happens neither than a dead android bot lying down with a red traiangle.

IS THERE ANYONE IN THE WORLD TO HELP ME!!!!.

Comment: Same issue (different viewpoint): [can't use adb shell in recovery mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56154/16575). According to the comments there, ideas from [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) have already been tried without success. `fastboot -w` seems to be no option as OP wasn't able to enter fastboot mode either. `adb shell` seems to have trouble finding `/system/bin/sh` in recovery.

Comment: You are correct lzzy but my bootloader doesnt support fastboot now adb shell gives permission denied error 13