# Micromax A88 too many pattern attempts issue?

Tags: lock-screens

My CellPhone MicroMax A88 locked and it is showing

```
Too Many Pattern attempts 
To unlock, sign in with your Google account.
```

My 'WiFi' is Off and my `Mobile Data` is also not enabled. I am not able to start internet on this phone.

Then I press Volume `Key Up + Power Button + Home Button` and reset my phone but still same issue.

I already saw [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection) but nothing worked. Can anyone tell me is their any other alternative to solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection).

Comment: I have tried maximum solution provided by this link but no any solution thats why i asked question

Comment: @dotVezz Are there any other alternatives, given that the answers in that link didn't work for him? Should we leave this question open?

Comment: I agree to leaving it open considering that, yeah.

Comment: I already mentioned i used worst condition factory reset but same issue any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution What I did?

1- Press Volume `Up+Power+Home` Button it show three option

- Fast Boot
- Normal Boot
- Settings

2- Then i clicked Settings then it have lots of option i selected `Factory reset/Delete` and click on `Menu` button ,this button you can see with `Home` Button then it again show `Delete User Data` then again Menu Button Some more option and then Ok to delete User Data.

It Resolved my Issue.