# locked out with wifi off

Tags: google-account, locked-out

I have an Aakash android tablet. The tablet was locked by too many patten attempts. Now I have to give my google account to log in. But the WiFi is not turned on in the tab. So I cannot log in with Google account. There is no hard reset in this tab. Tryed to go to recovery mode my pressing volume and power on. It too didn't work. Now what can I do??

Comment: As you've already correctly used the `locket-out` tag, you could start checking [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) (always a good idea, as those often contain first-aid). You then will be pointed to our most complete collection of possible solutions to this issue: [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Comment: Non of that answers provide a solution for my problem

Comment: Then you might wish to [edit] your question and write a) what you already tried and how that worked out, plus b) what other ideas you didn't try and why not. To give good answers, we need good background. And unless you can point out what makes your question different from that other one, it will probably be closed as duplicate.