# root android device without USB debugging

Tags: lock-screens, root-access, samsung-galaxy-note-2, locked-out

Is it possible to root a galaxy note 2 locked with a pattern screen lock? I am locked out of my phone . I thought if I can root the device then i would be able to remove screen lock through admin mode but for rooting need to enable USB debugging which I am not able to thanks the phone being locked in the first place. IS there a way out of this ?

Comment: Have you had a look through this question: [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/) A few of the answers in there should be relevant to you, and not all of them need rooting.

Comment: will check it out. Is there a way I can enable/disable USB debugging through command line or ADB ?