# Locked out of my Samsung Galaxy S Duos (forgot password)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, locked-out

I had set a security password on my Samsung Galaxy S Duos mobile and unfortunately forgot the unlock password. I tried hundred's of times to unlock my phone with many possible passwords but was unsuccessful in each of my attempts. Please help me unlock my phone and send me the master code (if any) to unlock the phone.

Comment: There's no such thing like a "master password". I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question; [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) gives you first-aid. So does our "canonical question" on the topic: [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that if you entered an incorrect unlock password too many times then it would ask you to enter your Google Account password to confirm your identity?

Have you not had this option when trying passwords?

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't the Google account password option as Johnny said you will have to wipe the phone back to factory settings using KIES on your computer.