# Samsung Galaxy S4: Get files from broken & locked screen

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4, data-recovery, locked-out, broken-screen

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4. I broke the screen a few days back and it was locked at the time. The phone is working because it can charge and I can hear the alarm and incoming calls and messages but I can't see a thing because it is all black. I can't possibly unlock the phone because the touch is not working too. I need to retrieve my files from the phone. So when I connect my phone using a USB to my MAC, it shows me absolutely nothing except this error:

```
 If your device's screen is locked, disconnect its USB cable, unlock your screen, and then reconnect the USB cable.
```

Like I said, I cannot unlock the screen. I can't use Samsung's `Find my Phone` application because I never added a Samsung Account to it and so my device is not registered for remote data recovery. 
[image]
When I connect my phone to my HP laptop via USB, it shows nothing, not even an error.

Is there any way I can unlock my phone remotely and retrieve my files?

Comment: I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question. Please follow up to [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), and especially to [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) as for the unlock part. For the file retrieval, do the same for the [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the S4 supports [USB On-The-Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go). If you get yourself an OTG adapter, you can use it to plug in a USB mouse and unlock the screen that way. A mouse click/drag works just like a screen touch in Android.

Comment: Do you mean, I could connect the OTG adapter to my computer and see my screen on my laptop? Because like I said, my S4 screen is black and I cant see a thing.

Comment: No, he means you can plug a standard USB keyboard or mouse directly into your phone with an [OTG adapter](http://www.amazon.com/eForCity-Micro-USB-OTG-Adapter/dp/B005QX7KYU). Use the keyboard to type in the unlock code, or use the mouse to click and drag to unlock, then unplug the keyboard/mouse and plug the phone into the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I used an OTG adapter and a keyboard. Plugged it in and then powered up. Typed in my code then plugged into laptop running Kies. Got all my contacts and messages and more