# my phone's display is damaged and i need to transfer all the data from the phone but it has a screen lock, what can be done?

Tags: sony-xperia-z1

my phone's display is damaged and there's a crack on it's screen too.
before getting the phone repaired i need to transfer all the data from the phone to my mac but i am facing a problem while doing this. to transfer the data the phone needs to be unlocked and my phone is locked via a pattern lock. i tried randomly the pattern on the phone's screen but it dint work out. i need an alternative that would help me unlock the phone so that i may transfer all the data. Please help.

Comment: You might wish to check [related questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=unlock+broken+screen+answers%3A1), especially: [Samsung Galaxy S4: Get files from broken & locked screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/71754/16575) / [S3 screen broken, developer mode on, how to transfer data](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75248/16575) / [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Get a USB on-the-go cable, connect a mouse to it and use it to unlock your device..