# i8960 performing awkwardly

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung

My Samsung Galaxy Core i8960 has a minor crack in lower right corner and sometimes has trouble detecting taps.

Once I manage to unlock it via pin I get to the lock screen that requires me to enter a password, now the problem is, my password is not accepted, apparently when setting it some keys weren't recorded and now I cannot get past this.

Is there any other way than to perform a reset? I have all my contacts on there and several photos that I'd preffer not to be deleted.

When I try to access files via PC, the phone is shown empty, so I can't just copy anything...

Comment: Worth a look, as it mentions a lot of methods: [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Comment: thanks for this, I've checked it, but my wifi is off, to increase battery life, so the options with google play are not working. entering password wrong 10 times only locks it for 30s, so I can't even get to google play login, the phone is relatively new, so I haven't rooted it and the remaining solutions seem not to work

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer reset, and if it's only about your contacts and photos, you can sync them to your Google account. Go to `Settings > Select "Google" under Accounts > Click on your Google Account` and now select `Contacts` and `People Details`. For backing up photos from your phone, you can upload them to Google Drive using Google Drive App. 
 After reset is completed, all your contacts will be automatically synchronized from your Google account.

Comment: the problem is, I can't get to settings, since my password is not accepted...