# Cant access my samsung galaxy tab 3 for kids as my google account is blocked

Tags: google

My son has blocked my daughters Samsung galaxy Tab 3 for kids.  It wont recognise my google account as it has exceeded the 5 tries. I have tried holding down the home, sound and power buttons and the little man appears but I don't get any msg about factory reset. Can anyone help?

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848/30530) answer which may help you to get back in without factory resetting.

Answer (score 0):

How to hard reset:

Warning! All data will be lost! Use this at your own risk!

1.Turn off your tablet

2.Push together volume up + home key + power key until Samsung logoo appears

3.Select with volume key "wipe data" and push power key to confirm

4.Select "yes" and push power key to confirm

5.Wait until format ends

6.Push power key to confirm "reboot"

7.Wait until the tablet restarts