# Unlock encrypted Android from ADB

Tags: adb, 4.4-kitkat, data-recovery, encryption, password

I have the following problem: Somehow, this evening the touchscreen of my Sony Xperia Z broke. I have two thin cracks in the display and everything on the right side of the crack does not react.
I have backup phones but I wanted to get back at least my photos. My device is encrypted with a passphrase, but I cannot type. My idea was, to unlock it from adb, so I can backup my data.
I run SlimKat (SlimRom) with TeamWin Recovery.

When I enter recovery mode, I can see my phone:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
CB5A1PN2WU  recovery
```

But no commands work:

```
$ adb shell
- exec '/system/bin/sh' failed: No such file or directory (2) -
```

How can I get my data? Can I remotely control my keyboard? Sadly, everything is saved on the internal flash memory.

Comment: Welcome to the site, strix.   Variations of this question have been asked before, you might try a search on "unlock with adb", although I didn't see an obvious solution for you. [This post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection) also has a detailed answer that may be useful to you.

Comment: I have read this before. The problem is: for all these solutions I need a working touch screen or a running phone. My phone is encrypted and turned off. I don't have either touch nor adb shell working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xperia Z supports USB-on-the-go, so with a USB-OTG adaptor and a USB keyboard you should be able to enter the encryption passphrase to boot the device.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Worked like a charm, and getting all my data for 6$ was more than worth it!

Answer (score 2):

Although buying an OTG cable should work fine, there is in fact a way to unlock your device through ADB alone. Found this out the hard way when I included a character in my password that was not typable on the virtual keyboard *and* an OTG cable did not work for reasons I won't get into.

There are two ADB commands with which you can trigger keyboard events. I have tested these and they both work on the disk decryption key input screen. These commands are:

- `adb shell input text 'mytext'` emulates typing `mytext` onto the keyboard. Note that it does not accept *arbitrary* text: you can mostly use this to send ASCII vowels, consonants and digits to the keyboard in this way. Special characters (e.g. `'`, `#`, `;`) including the space bar using this command either require special syntax or are not accepted.
- `adb shell inputevent <event_number>` emulates the event of a specific key press. This can be used to type certain special characters. The full list of key events can be seen in the [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_0). Although the key events supported differ per Android version, all key events you would use for typing in a password have been supported since Android 3.0 (API level 11).

See this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events) for more information.