# Samsung GT-S5360 screen unlock

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out

My mother has forgotten her screen lock password. is a four digit number. how can I reset phone so she can use it again?

Please assist!

Comment: I've just added the 'locked-out' tag to your question. Could you please check if [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) gets you started? Especially see: [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this process only if mobile data is disabled and phone PIN locked. What I'm giving is Factory Reset method.
*(Warning: Factory reset erases all the data from the phone permanently. Phones resets to its initial state.)*

- Charge the phone fully.
- Switch-off the phone.
- Try these combinations -

> volume key up+middle home key+power key

-or-

> volume key down+middle home key+power key

- A windows pop-ups for confirming Factory Reset/Wipe Data. Confirm it.
- The reset process completes in a minute or two.

Comment: You should hold all the keys for few seconds when trying different combinations.

Comment: Aw. That's the last-resort only, MANI. There are ways to reset the lock without resetting the device. And what you describe is not a [hard-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-reset/info) (kill the power supply), but a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) (killing all "custom data and configuration"). Unfortunately, these two terms are frequently confused ;)

Comment: @anish - Mark this as answer anish. It solved the problem right.

Answer (score -1):

You can take the help of Google account to reset the password, first of all make sure the wifi/mobile data is turned on, if not then switch the data connection on by pressing and holding the power button until a pop up appears asking you wether to turn the device off, Data network mode use it to turn the mobile data switched on. Once mobile data gets switched on tap over the forgot password put your gmail account user ID and password you will be given the privilege to create new password. Follow the instruction and you are all done.

Comment: You don't find 'Data network mode' when power button long pressed. Give another suggestion.

Comment: Well, yes its available over the Samsung devices running JellyBean. I got the option while pressing and holding the power button I wonder why you are not getting the option to do so. Are you trying it correctly ?? I would say try doing the same again and let me know what are the options you are getting while pressing and holding the power button.