# I locked my phone from android device manager, now i'm not being able to remove the lock screen password

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, security, android-device-manager

I locked my phone from android device manager, now i'm not being able to remove the lock screen password, it says that, lock screen is disabled by administrator or encryption policy or credential storage
I tried clearing the credentials, but it didn't work

Comment: See if this helps: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93750/how-can-i-unlock-my-phone-i-locked-it-using-android-device-manager-but-it-clai

Answer (score 1):

Different Devices have different options to go into recovery mode. Specify your device I will tell you how to go into your device's recovery mode! After going into recovery mode try

1. Wipe Data/ Factory Reset
2. Wipe Cache Partition

And then reboot your device. It Will Work!!