# I tested the "lock" feature on Android Device Manger, and now I can't unlock it

Tags: lock-screens, android-device-manager

I was just testing out Android Device Manager and I tested the lock feature. I entered a password, as requested, and the phone was locked. I was told that since I already had a lock screen on my phone, the password wouldn't be needed. I went back to Android Device Manager and there is only a "lock" option, not an "unlock" option.

Now I can't access my phone since it won't allow me to enter the password on the phone, or unlock it from Android Device Manager.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Have you checked with our other [device manager questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-device-manager) already – e.g. [How can I unlock my phone? I locked it using Android Device Manager, but it claims I entered a wrong password](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/93750/16575) or [How to unlock Google Device Manager remote lock?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/68687/16575)

Answer (score 0):

you have not mentioned which phone you are using, but i found this step in XDA forum, and this seems to have solved it. Could you check if one of the solution helps you: [xda-adm-unlock](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2767278), check out the post #3 by maysider.
Here is the complete snip of the sollution from XDA:

> so the BUG is "made by Samsung". Samsung just do not accept any
>   correct PIN or password (maybe because of "wrong" keyboard).
>   could anyone tell me how to remove the lock without wipe? thx
>
> edit:
>
> solution 1) just if you have debugging mode on then follow this
>   solution http://maxoberberger.net/blog/2013/08/unlock-android-device-using-adb/
>
> solution 2) just if you can change your keyboard for another (if you
>   are allowed when entering password)
>
> solution 3) just if you have Samsung account, log into Samsung Dive >>
>   "unlock" (my case)
>
> solution 4) no debuging mode + no keyboard solution + no samsung
>   account? >> just and only wipe through recovery or Google Device
>   Manager
>
> Happy now, but I was lucky
>
> SAMSUNG BUG in 100 %

HTH.

**Edit by Izzy:** The link with "solution 1" proposes changes made with ADB, which require root access:

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases
sqlite3 settings.db
update system set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock';
update secure set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock';
update system set value=0 where name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently';
update secure set value=0 where name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently';
.quit
exit
adb reboot
```

This will unset your device lock completely, as if you did not have defined any.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your phone with its buttons
You can erase your locked phone using its power and volume buttons.

You first have to power off your android device. You will have to press and hold the volume down button along with the power button. Keep holding until you see Android images/buttons. Then release the buttons and then follow the volume down button to go for factory reset, afterward select the power button.

But this is a risky plan as you will lose all your data. After resetting when u will turn it on it will ask to set up your phone. After setting up you are completely ready to use your phone and from now on be alert do not put lock patterns if u easily forget them.