# Locked phone with Android Device Manager and can't remember the password

Tags: locked-out, android-device-manager

I lost my phone and used Android Device Manager to lock it. However, it turns out my boyfriend was last logged into my Gmail, so his phone is the one that was locked and now I can't remember the password!

How can we unlock his phone?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts!  Please see [How to unlock Google Device Manager remote lock?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/68687/16575) (plus the questions in its "Linked" section), [How can I unlock my phone? I locked it using Android Device Manager, but it claims I entered a wrong password](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/93750/16575), and [similar questions with answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=device+manager+lock+answers%3A1) for a starter.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution,Hard reset your phone and do a reset factory settings in recovery mode. BTW which phone model you are using, I guess it must be Samsung :)

### updated

One more way, if you know your phone is rooted and ADB on..
You have to delete all your key files from system folder. Try this.
Connect you device with usb and run following command. If you are not able to do so, i am afraid. You need a full wipe.

```
adb devices
adb shell
cd data/system
su
rm *.key
```

Even if shows lock screen after reboot, try a easy random pattern/password.

Comment: Are you sure that's the only way – and there's nothing to be tried before losing all data? [This answer to a similar question](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/93756/16575) seems to show otherwise: Use device manager again to set another password (and this time remember it), then use that.

Comment: @Izzy sadly that's not the case anymore or it is different from device to device. But I just tested that, remotely locking the device twice, and got this error message "Since google has verified that a screen lock is already set, the password that you entered won’t be needed"

Comment: @jer3my That's what I "like" so much about Google (and MS as well). They always know better what we need than we do :( Sorry to read that!

Comment: @Izzy Yeah, But don't worry I don't have this problem. I remember my passwords. Not saying the OP is lying, but often time's people just want to get into phones they aren't meant to get into and they think ADM will let them do that. So the "no need to relock the phone" is another safety feature, in my opinion.

Comment: @jer3my valid points. But in order to use ADM, one would need the credentials of the associated Google account.

Comment: @izzy Yep. That's why even if you are logged into gmail/g+/etc, I am glad Google requires you to relog in to use ADM.

Comment: Note that on on most versions of Android your phone has to be unlocked for USB or network debugging to be enabled, so this method may not work if you restarted the phone and are trying to plug it into your computer as ADB will be unable to connect to the locked phone.

Answer (score 0):

sorry that is probably too late, but I found a solution.  You have to sign in to a SAMSUNG account, and there is an unlock feature.
If it doesn't work the first time, locked it with a 4 digit pin from the same Samsung page, in the cell enter the code and the lock will be temporarily removed but the screen lock will still be in place, so then again Unlock it from the Samsung tool.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my LG Nexus 4. I just logged into Android Device Manager and set another password. No need to remember the old password!