# Android device manager unlock

Tags: android-device-manager

i was trying the feature lock by Andriod device manager but now the fone is not accepting my password . how do i unlock it? please help

Comment: What password did you put in the Device Manager? you have to put the same on the phone to unlock it

Comment: Have you seen [these related questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-device-manager), especially [How can I unlock my phone? I locked it using Android Device Manager, but it claims I entered a wrong password](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/93750/16575) and [How to unlock Google Device Manager remote lock?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/68687/16575)