# locked galaxy tab 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, locked-out

Please help. Am locked out of tablet. Keeps saying wrong password even though I know it is correct. Have tried on and volume. Have tried on and home button. Can only get password screen. What next?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question. Please first check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for some first aid, which hopefully will already solve your issue. Then come back here and either answer (and accept) your question if solved, or [edit] it to explain what you've tried and where you're stuck. Thanks, and keeping my fingers crossed!

Answer (score -1):

First go to the recovery mode of your device. Every device has its own method for recovery. If you are able to go to recovery then go to it and navigate to factory data reset and select it. It will reset your phone and after turning on your phone, the lock system will be disabled.

Comment: Hard method. There are alternatives in many cases, see [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) ;)