# How To Bypass Android Lock-Screen?

Tags: lock-screens

I can't remember the pattern to my phone anymore. How can I bypass it? I've looked at my options but they've been whittled down. Android debugging isn't enabled, so I can't use the Android SDK to access the console, as one article suggested. And I'm unable to use the "Bypass Screen Lock" app on Google Play to get in, as I can't remember my google account info- which means, of course, that I can't just use the "forgot your password?" option, either.

The phone in question is a StraightTalk Galaxy S2 running Anroid 2.3.6

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you don't know the google account and password, your only real option is to wipe the phone (factory reset).

Comment: Related: [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection)

Answer (score -1):

If you logged in with your google account, you should be able to see a forgot password option after you enter the wrong password 5 times. your google password will let you reset it.

Comment: In the question "I can't remember my google account info".