# Sony Xperia ST21i forgotten PIN help

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out

I set a PIN screen lock on my Sony ST21i (Android 4.0) and forgot the code. No encryption, no root, and the phone won't show up a "Forgot PIN?" button. How to regain access to my phone? There is no important information in it, so any solution that deletes all data is fine. Help!

Edit: Didn't work:

- Android Device Manager
- Trying to boot into "recovery mode" using various key combinations found online

Comment: The phone does not (and won't) ask me for my Google account information, unlike the pattern lock case.

Comment: Can you explain what Recovery options you tried? A factory reset will wipe all settings, including your PIN.

Comment: Have you checked with our [locked-out tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), its first-aid and the questions/solutions linked from there – especially [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)