# How to unlock the Lock Screen in Android Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, locked-out

How can I unlock the screen lock in `Android Lollipop` *without losing data*?

I have forgotten the pattern.

Comment: I have just added the `locked-out` tag to your question. Please follow up to [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) for first-aid. Hint: Answers on [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) cover pretty much any known method concerning your issue.

Answer (score -1):

**method 1**Try using adb pull with the android SDK
In recovery mode.

**method 2**If you have a phone without an SD card wiping data will only remove the apps otherwise the data will be fine. This works even in some phones without SD card.

**method 3 easiest**After several tries it will give you option of forgot password. Which will ask you Google account details. Fill it and you are good to go.

Comment: How do method 1, or method 2, unlock the phone?