# Recover photos and/or bypass lock screen on Android 5.0

Tags: adb, 5.0-lollipop, data-recovery, locked-out, android-device-manager

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 which I dropped on the ground so the screen broke. I had a swipe lock enabled. To be able to unlock it before it was repaired I locked it through Android Device Manager and tried to send commands to it from ADB. I was unsuccessful. The phone was repaired but wasn't wiped but now I can't access it. It keeps saying incorrect pin even though I know I've entered the pin I set through Android Device Manager.

I can't seem to set a new pin through ADM it says it's not needed since it is already protected by a pin.

Is there any way I can access my phone? Either:

- Backup my pictures and then reset the phone
- Bypass the lock somehow (I have ADB access and debug mode enabled)

I've tried all sorts of guides with ADB shell to remove *.key files but they don't work either because I don't have permission or because su or sqlite3 doesn't exist.

I'd prefer if I could keep the stock android image on the phone.

Comment: I've just updated the tags on your question. Two places you want to see first are our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) (for bypassing the lock screen), plus the [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) for the other part of your question. Our tag-wikis often contain some first-aid or links to the "top" related questions – always a good idea to check :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The locked out wiki seems to apply to older versions of Android and/or rooted devices. As for data-recovery, it seems to be for deleted files. My files are not deleted, just not accessible.

Comment: There might be some version-specific hints in, but also many version agnostic hints (as e.g. [installing that app to disable keyguard](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848/16575), see second item). As for data recovery: here you're right, the wiki focusses on exactly that – my bad, sorry for that. Though I still thing the tag is correct, as the data is currently inaccessible to you.

Comment: The Screen Lock Bypass specifically says "This app will not work on Android 4.1 or above" so it's not version agnostic.

Comment: Ouch – sorry, I didn't check the app for a while. What about the ADB tricks mentioned there? I know, you've tried "something" with ADB – but was it especially that?