# My android's wifi is off and I am prompted for the passcode.

Tags: locked-out

I entered the pattern wrongly too many times, and now it wants my google password. I now remember my pattern. How can I access it? (No online things please.) The original question's answers didn't work. Help! (please...?)

Comment: Check this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection

Comment: Please elaborate on what, specifically, you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: "The original question's answers didn't work. "