# After Factory Reset, how do you unlock phone when it is not connected to wifi?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s, factory-reset, locked-out

I can't use my Samsung i9000 (Galaxy S1) for a number of years because I tried the screen lock incorrectly too many times. I no longer get that option, it just says "Too many pattern attempts" and asks for your Gmail details. But even after a factory reset, its still asking for these details and the phone is not connected to wifi. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: It shouldn't know about that after a factory-reset – it rather should behave as if it came "straight from the shop". Which raises the question whether your factory-reset was successful at all. // I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question. Please take a look at [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), which contains some background info on that as well as fist-aid and further links on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Till i understand, factory reset will completely erase all data which includes all settings also. So are you sure you have factory reset your device?

As mentioned [here](http://www.matthewhollander.com/locked-out-of-your-android-phone/) if you have USB debugging ON on your device you can follow this steps to disable lock:-

**How to Disable Pattern Lock via ADB**

- You must have previously enable USB Debugging (Settings ->
  Application -> Development -> USB Debugging)
- Download and extract the Android SDK (from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html))
- Plug your phone into your computer
- In command line navigate to where you extracted the SDK, then to the Tools folder which should contain adb.exe. Do not simply run adb.exe but instead enter adb –d shell.

Please check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection) question of forum