# Forgotten password: How do I disable the screenlock in Sony Xperia Z2?

Tags: factory-reset, locked-out, sony-xperia-z2

I have a Sony Xperia Z2 upgraded to Lollipop 5.0 and I forgot my pattern lock. There is no "forgot password" or anything. How can I remove the code or fix it? If there is no solution to my problem, then how do I  factory reset the phone.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! As that's a quite frequent question here, we've set up some first-aid for it in our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info). Especially see [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) It has a collection of avalable methods to chose from. Good luck! // As for the "last resort", that's called *factory-reset* and is [described here](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info).

Answer (score 0):

Once you solve that, I recommend you install an app like Cerberus and add it as administrator. Yesterday I forgot my phone at home, but was able to send it a command to unlock the phone and other things. When I got home, my phone still was unlocked.