# Can't unlock Android

Tags: lock-screens, password, locked-out, android-device-manager

My Phone is locked, and I forgot the pin code. I tried to reset password using Android device manager, but it failed, I can't unlock device with new changed password. But when sending Ring using ADM (Just to make sure it detects phone) it works fine.

I cannot remote wipe or hard reset because I want the data. Please suggest the way to recover the Phone storage?

PS: Phone isn't rooted, and is connected to WIFI.

Thanks.

Comment: No! phone isn't rooted. And by Phone data I meant Phone storage. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit you question to include your comment. You can always edit your own question.

Comment: You can find most options to unlock your device after a lockout in this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection
Have you tried all of those?

Comment: Have you been asked to login using your Google a/c?

Comment: @gertmenkel Thanks  for providing very informative link. I will definitely try solutions from it, and will update here if my issue gets resolved.

Comment: @MorrisIriga, no I haven't been asked to login using Google A/c.

Comment: Your device should always ask for your Google password as a fallback. I know in kitkat "forgot my password" showed up in the bottom right corner.