# Access phone contacts by PC without USB debugging in android

Tags: locked-out

My little sister entered my phone screen pattern incorrectly. My phone went to a screen that needs my Google account and password. When I enter them, it says that they are invalid. I am sure that they are correct (also I can't enable internet in that screen). I searched about it a lot and realized that this is a bug in android. I am prevented from unlocking my phone.
I can factory reset my device, but my contact list is important and I don't have any back up of it. Is there anyway to access it? Here are two solutions that may help to solve this problem.

1. I can access my device storage by connecting a USB cable. There are some windows apps that can access to contact list by USB like `adb` or `Wondershare MobileGo`, but they need USB debbugging to have been enabled. On my device, it is off and I can't toggle it because my phone is locked.

2.can i root my device in this state and after that solve my problem?

3. I can make a back up from my device. It made a `.backup` file on my phone storage. Is there any windows app that can extract data like "contact list" from that `.backup` file?

Comment: If you can't enable Internet and Google credentials are considered incorrect by the system and if you don't have a custom recovery and if ADB is not enabled and the device in unrooted (assuming) too then positive chances are less to none. My point, did you have Google Contacts sync enabled before the device locked out? Google will restore your contacts after a reset. // That `.backup` point, are you using some Chinese phone? I've one such  phone whose stock recovery allows creating a `.backup` file, though I never bothered to extract anything from it.

Comment: In case the device is rooted, you may be in luck: [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848) Anyhow, tell us which device is it and is it under warranty?

Comment: tank you.my phone is chinese. but my google contacts is not sync.cant i use the usb mass storage to access my contacts list?

Comment: USB mass storage provides clients like PC explicit  access to external SD card. That's all it does. Anyhow, what about my other points raised in my earlier comment?

Comment: none of them work for me.but about the .backup file.i can factory reset my phone and after that restore to my previous account using that file.but after that i return back to that first screen that wants username and pass