# Locked out of Galaxy S Duos - Failed lock pattern

Tags: locked-out, pattern-lock, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562 which is now locked with too many failed pattern attempts. I don't remember the pin for it.

I've changed my password for Google account from laptop and I wanted to login from the locked out phone but it says *wrong password/username*.
But I can log in on laptop. I'm using mobile data connection to sign in to google account.

Please someone help me as I don't want to hard reset, I have important data on it.

Comment: You mean you've forgotten the lock screen pattern as well as the Google account password?

Comment: no the pattrn atempts are done by small kids i remmber pattern but it is not working...yes i forgot the google password but i reset it from laptop and tried again to login but it didn't work

Comment: any other way??

Comment: [This link](http://visihow.com/Recover_Android_Device_in_case_of_Forgot_password/pattern_unlock_an_Android_device) may be useful. Check that out. :)

Comment: Have you tried setting a temporary password using the android device manager?

Comment: Can you pull down the notification bar from your lockscreen? If so, this app will get all your files off the device without root: [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.gillion.lockedphonebackup) Just install from website, insert an SD card or USB with "copy-here.txt", click "app installed" notification from lock screen, and profit.

Answer (score 0):

Try all the methods in a similar question on here: [Izzy's Answer on Unlocking Android Devices via Google, ADB, and Recovery - Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848/101950)

There are almost 10 angles to work from running 3 pages long, it is too much to quote here and all credit goes to Izzy for spending a lot of time working up that answer.

If none of those work, please revise your answer to include any errors you encountered and whether your device is rooted, knowledge of installed Android version, build number, etc.

Hope this helps,

Comment: This is a comment unnecessarily posted as an answer.  If you think the linked  answer fits the question then see if the current  question is a duplicate of the question behind the link. In any case, if you intend to keep this as an answer please quote the relevant parts here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The link you provided seems helpful =)

Answer (score 0):

You can unlock your Android device by using the ADB. Run the Commands given below:

USB Debugging should be enabled to use the steps mentioned below

Adb shell

Rm /data/system/gesture/key

After that reboot your android device and run the following commands

Adb shell

cd /data/data/com.android.providers.setting¬s/databases

sqlite3 settings.db

update system set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock';

update system set value=0 where name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently';

.quit

You can take help from this article while performing the above steps:
http://www.what-is.in/howto/reset-android-pattern-after-too-many-wrong-attempts.html

Comment: The developer(s) of that linked site seems to be careful. They didn't mention the date of publishing of an article anywhere on a page, neither the author's name is mentioned. This makes it *bit* hard to verify for us whether the answer containing a link for such website is genuine or an attempt to spam (that is, to draw traffic to the site). // Are you affiliated to the linked site?

Comment: I am not associated with the website anyway. I just use the same instructions as shown this blog and found them helpful. That's why I recommended the same here.