# Galaxy S5 mini - Locked and I don't know the alternate password

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, locked-out, fingerprint

For some reason my Galaxy S5 mini (SM-G800) is locked and asking for the alternate password instead of my fingerprint. I already restarted it, took of the battery, but it always goes to the same locked screen on boot.

I also tried the [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) on my google account. I tried the Lock option, changing the password, but since the phone was already locked, it is not working. By the way, the phone WiFi is on.

I searched a lot and found no solution besides resetting my phone and loosing everything. The are a lot of photos and stuff that I don't want to loose! So the reset is still not an option.

It seams so stupid that I own the google account registered on the phone, I own the fingerprint to login and I know everything is inside the phone, but I cant login! Any simple email account have a forget password option! Why the fingerprint login does not come back!?? Stupid programmers!!

[Some sites](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/395840-fingerprint-scanner-alternate-password-stopped-working.html) says that after about 20 incorrect passwords tries it would give me an option to logging using my google account, but I already tried a lot of password and the only thing that happens is a wait 30 seconds countdown !

Edit 1: Just found out this site [www.unlockscreen.com](http://www.unlockscreen.com) but I don't know it is some kind of fishing/trojan or the real deal.

Edit 2: It seems my version of Android and/or fingerprint does not have the "forgotten button". It never appears. Also, I don't want to loose the warranty.

Comment: Do you know your email? Maybe, it's possible to change your password using a computer and your phone might sync to it.

Comment: If you're afraid of your photo, you can go to http://photos.google.com

Comment: @ChristopherAngelo I know my email, but the alternate password is not linked to it, it is internal to the phone fingerprint. My photos are not synced

Comment: Try all the methods in a similar question on here: [Izzy's Answer on Unlocking Android Devices via Google, ADB, and Recovery - Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848/101950)

Comment: Thanks @AaronGillion, I did not try everything that is listed there, but most of it does not work. I was thinking, ins't there an app that I can install through google.play site that does a full backup of my data?

Comment: I searched using a lot of keywords and surprised that I couldn't find an app. That just means I have to make one. Will be on Play Store soon!

Comment: Currently developing the app. Everything is going my direction except on Jellybean up, the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` doesn't fire the app automatically after Play Store installation until the app is explicitly launched for the first time. Do you have access to your notification pulldown to hit the "app installed" text to launch the app?

Comment: @AaronGillion no access, but I have access to always on top (floating) app, like the remote TV app icon. But i think this doesn't help the first time launch problem..

Comment: Once you're in the remote app you can't pull notifications either?

Comment: No I can't. It is all locked.

Comment: Ok. Try opening Emergency Dialer and call 411 or 911 and see if pulldown works while call is in session.

Comment: also no, didnt work

Comment: Don't lose hope! Do you have access to the keyboard, along with the key to swap default keyboards? While on topic, try plugging in a USB keyboard with an OTG adapter and start hammering away with the keys to see if you can find a hole in the dialer/lockscreen.

Comment: I just tested the external keyboard on my S6: the media buttons launch default music app in background (could be helpful), and Ctrl+Alt+Delete ***immediately*** reboots the device from lockscreen, no warning. Legendary!

Comment: My warranty expires at day 11. So I'm running out of time, I guess I will end up flashing some kind of recovery OS. I don't have an OTG adapter. :/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this works or not, but according to [this post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/395840-fingerprint-scanner-alternate-password-stopped-working.html#post4920411):

> just unlock it via findmymobile.samsung.com
>   you either need to already have an account there or just setup one.
>   you can simply unlock it via this service.

Since it's an official Samsung service instead of a sketchy third-party one, it seems like it's worth a try. I don't think it will work though, unless if you've already set up a Samsung account on your phone and given it remote access.

Comment: There is the need to setup the account inside the phone first. I've never done that, so my phone is not listed on the findmymobile!

Comment: I know this seems kind of dumb to ask, but have you given the fingerprint sensor a thorough cleaning? Some people reported that doing this fixed their problem.

Comment: The phone is not trying to use the sensor I guess. It is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Android has a password forgotten button. Maybe you have to enter a few times a wrong password. Then you can use your email to log in.

Another option is to root your phone. You will lose your guaranty and normally I don't recommend this to people who don't know what this is or what they do.

I think there is a possibility to root your phone without loosing data (but I am not sure) and then it should be possible to reset the password or to make a backup from your data. If rooting is an option for you you can search for it.

Comment: It seams my version of Android and/or fingerprint does not have this "forgotten button". It never appears. I don't want to loose the warranty.

Comment: Is it possible to root a locked phone?

Comment: It depends on the phone but Samsung phones can be rooted using Odin and for this you have to be in download mode. So I think it's possible to root a locked phone