# Is it possible to pull data in ADB sideload mode

Tags: adb, backup, locked-out

My phone is locked, [as explained here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135685/galaxy-s5-mini-locked-and-i-dont-know-the-alternate-password).

Since I can't find the password, I want to backup my data before a reset. I've just installed Android Studio and Samsung USB driver.

- Boot my phone on "apply update from ADB" mode.
- Open Windows CMD, run adb.exe devices
- It list my device as sideload mode

How can I pull my data now??

**Is there a way I can backup my data before a reset and without voiding the warranty??**

Answer (score 1):

No, in "sideload mode" you can only apply updates via `adb sideload filename.zip`, no other ADB commands are available, except `adb devices` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem. Look at this:
[How-To Geek - How to Copy TWRP Android Backups to Your PC for Safe Keeping](https://www.howtogeek.com/240655/how-to-copy-twrp-android-backups-to-your-pc-for-safe-keeping/)

In case you have TWRP installed or manage to somehow do so, then remember to take out the "Enable MTP" option in the "Mount" section of TWRP.

Comment: Don't even know what TWRP is.